# update y concatenar columnas POSTGRESSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

me gustaría que me ayuden con esta duda. quiero hacer un update en un atributo nuevo que agregue a mi tabla, la situación  es la siguiente al hacer ese update quiero concatenar tres columnas. cuando ejecuto este código:

```
update saber2012_1 set estu_fecha_nacimiento = Concat(estu_nacimiento_dia,'/',estu_nacimiento_mes,'/',estu_nacimiento_anno);
```

me pone nulos muchos atributos que antes tenían valores por ejemplo lo que ven en nulo en la imagen antes tenia sus valores respectivos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no le falta una condicion de where a esa consulta? si no, lo hace para toda la tabla

Comment: Si, es que quiero que lo haga para toda la tabla.

Comment: y vos podes asegurar que tenian valores? porque un update no cambia valores que no le digas que cambie...

Comment: Si claro, es que yo importo lo datos y luego hago el proceso. pero después de que ejecuto el código me pone esos valores en nulos. Osea antes de ejecutar ese código si tiene datos todas las columnas que ves en nulo.

Comment: Con la informacion q das, el tema es irreproducible. Algo esta cambiando tus columnas y no es ese update